# Given $T_2((0,0),(h_1,h_2))=1+2h_1^2-3h_2^2$ and $g_h(t)=f(th),$ what are possible values of $g_h'(0)$ and $g_h''(0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> Let $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ be a function of the class $C^2$ whose Taylor polynomial of degree $2$ at $(0,0)$ is given by $$T_2((0,0),(h_1,h_2))=1+2h_1^2-3h_2^2.$$ For a unit vector $h\in\Bbb R^2$ define a function $g_h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $g_h(t):=f(th).$ What are possible values of $g_h'(0)$ and $g_h''(0)$?

---

**My attempt:**

Since $h_1,h_2\in\Bbb R$ are independent, I think we can write down $T_2((0,0),(h_1,h_2))$ by definition and compare the coefficients of the polynomial on the $LHS$ with those on the $RHS$ to find the $\nabla f(0,0)$ and $H_f(0,0):$
$$\begin{aligned}
&f(0,0)+Df(0,0)(h_1,h_2)+ \frac1{2!}D^2f(0,0)((h_1,h_2),(h_1,h_2))\\
=&\ f(0,0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0,0)h_1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(0,0)h_2\\
&+\frac1{2!}\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}(0,0)h_1^2+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}(0,0)h_1h_2+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}(0,0)h_1h_2+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2}(0,0)h_2^2\right)\\
=&\ f(0,0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0,0)h_1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(0,0)h_2\\
&+\frac1{2!}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}(0,0)h_1^2+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}(0,0)h_1h_2+\frac1{2!}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2}(0,0)h_2^2
\end{aligned}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(0,0)=0,
\quad
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}(0,0)=0,
\quad 
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2}(0,0)=4,
\quad
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2}(0,0)=-6$$

$$\operatorname{grad}f(0,0)=(0,0), H_f(0,0)=\begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&-6\end{bmatrix}$$
So, $(0,0)$ is a stationary point, but $H_f(0,0)$ is indefinite, so $(0,0)$ isn't a point of the extreme, otherwise, $H_f(0,0)$ would be positive or negative semidefinite.

Next, $$g_h'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(th)-f(0,0)}t=\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}(0)=Df(0)h=0.$$

Now, let $\gamma:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2,\gamma(t)=th.$ Then $g_h''(0)=(f\circ\gamma)''(0).$

I tried computed it in a more general setting when $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ and $\gamma:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$:

$$\begin{aligned}(f\circ\gamma)'(c)=Df(\gamma (c))\gamma'(c)&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(\gamma(c))&\ldots&\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(\gamma(c))\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\gamma_1'(c)\\\vdots\\ \gamma'_n(c)\end{bmatrix}\\&=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\gamma(c))\gamma_j'(c)
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}D\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\gamma(c))\right)&=D\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\gamma(c))\gamma'(c)\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\partial x_j}(\gamma (c))&\ldots&\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_n\partial x_j}(\gamma(c))\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\gamma_1'(c)\\\vdots\\\gamma_n'(c)\end{bmatrix}\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\gamma(c))\gamma_i'(c)\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}(f\circ\gamma)''(c)&=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\gamma(c))\gamma_i'(c)\gamma_j'(c)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\gamma(c))\gamma_j''(c)\right)\\&=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\gamma(c))\gamma_i'(c)\gamma_j'(c)+\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(\gamma(c))\gamma_j''(c)\\&= Hf(\gamma(c))(\gamma'(c),\gamma'(c))+\nabla f(\gamma(c))\gamma''(c)\end{aligned}$$

So, $$\begin{aligned}g_h''(0)&=H_f(0,0)((h_1,h_2),(h_1,h_2))+\nabla f(0,0)\cdot(0,0)^T\\&=\begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&-6\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}h_1\\h_2\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}h_1\\h_2\end{bmatrix}\\&=4h_1^2-6h_2^2\\&=4(h_1^2+h_2^2)-10h_2^2\\&=4-10h_2^2\end{aligned}\\\implies g_h''(0)\in[-6,4]$$ because $h_2\in[-1,1]\implies h_2^2\in[0,1]$

Is my answer correct? Is there any other way of solving this?

Comment: Why do you revert the improved edit of your question? At the moment, your formula runs out of the page.

Comment: the width of the webpage is limited and you have a very long line that is out of the page, which is very difficult to read.